# about stative verbs, is there any complete list of these "adjectives"?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I am actually forwarding a kind of lexical on most frequent words used in Chinese (打有 com).
There are many of them which are used as stative verbs with common grammatical rules.
So i began to make a list of these words often used in Chinese language.
I am afraid to forget some of them, then is there any official list that i can get online ?

Here is my draft of list (number following hanzi is frequency in Wenlin dict.) :

大       12
小       49
方       64
好       66
美       92
高       100
老       109
长       110
全       127
新       135
正       140
重       152
少       196
真       214
安       262
贵       832
忙       891
圆       1020
饿       1640
胖       2043
帅       2260

高兴  200.8
漂亮  37.6
好看  31.5
精彩  7.7
凶残  5
愚蠢  3.3

Answer (score 1):

Stative verbs are a class of adjectives or descriptive words that behave in certain ways in sentences. Sometimes they can function like verbs. There are many of them, so I doubt there is a finite list. You may want to read up on them here:

https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Stative_verb

or here:

http://www.chinese-grammar.com/beginner/stative-verbs.html

In fact, google "stative verbs in Chinese", and you can find a ton of information on them.

Comment: Thank you for links (and a well list of modifiers), although i already know about the rules of these words (There are many of them which are used as stative verbs with common grammatical rules). I see they are 16 in 292 first characters (if i didn't miss any) so they would be around 6% (as single hanzis) ?  only a list would help us :-)